# Where is Mars in the night sky

Tags: planet, amateur-observing

I live around Houston, Texas and I'm taking advantage of Earth hour to look at the stars. I've found two objects that I think might be Mars. Both of them are in roughly the same plane as Venus and Jupiter. Both are closer to Venus than Jupiter. One of them has a reddish tint and is higher in the sky than Venus, and the other is closer to the horizon than venus. It is 8:50 as I type this. Is one of these Mars?

Comment: **March:** http://www.space.com/28735-best-planets-march-night-sky.html **April:** http://www.space.com/25387-brightest-planets-april-night-sky.html  **Typical search to get these:** https://www.google.com/search?q=planets+in+march+mars&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8

Answer (score 2):

At that time (20:50), and that location (Houston, Tx), Mars was closer to the horizon.
You can see that in the [sky-chart provided](http://heavens-above.com/wholeskychart.ashx?lat=29.7604&lng=-95.3698&loc=Houston&alt=15&tz=CST&size=800&SL=1&SN=1&BW=1&time=57101.07639&ecl=0&cb=0) by [heavens-above.com](http://heavens-above.com/skychart.aspx?lat=29.7604&lng=-95.3698&loc=Houston&alt=15&tz=CST) (attached below).

I cannot tell what's the other object you describe, but if you are not sure whether something is a planet or a star, the planets doesn't twinkle whether [the star does](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/222/why-do-stars-appear-to-twinkle).

[image: Sky-chart for Houston at 2015-03-29T20:50:00]

Answer (score 1):

You will be able to recognize Mars easily from its red color. Mars looks like a red tiny dot in the night sky.
You can always use apps such as Google sky map. You simply point your phone in the direction of the red dot and your phone will identify the object for you.